# spherical wave expansion

Tags: fourier-analysis, exponential-function, wave-equation

In the paper,

Sheen, David M., Douglas L. McMakin, and Thomas E. Hall. "Three-dimensional millimeter-wave imaging for concealed weapon detection." Microwave Theory and Techniques, IEEE Transactions on 49.9 (2001): 1581-1592.

the author decomposes the spherical wave into a superposition of plan-wave components
\begin{equation}
e^{-j2k\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+z_0^2}} = \iint_{R^2} e^{jk_{x'}(x'-x) + jk_{y'}(y'-y) + j k_z z_0} dk_{x'}dk_{y'}
\end{equation}

$e^{-j2k\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+z_0^2}}$ represents a spherical wave from $(x',y',z_0)$.
k_{x'} and k_{y'} are the Spatial frequency corresponding to x' and y'. $k = \frac{\omega}{c}, (2k)^2 = k_x^2 + k_y^2 + k_z^2$.

How is the formula deducted?

[image]

The physical process is as follows. As shown in the Figure. The source(transceiver position) is placed at $(x',y',z_0)$, and there is an object(our target) at position $(x,y,0)$. The target has a reflectivity function $f(x,y,z)$, the ratio of reflected field to incident field.

There is a receiver also at $(x',y',z_0)$. Its signal would be $s(x',y') = \iint f(x,y,z=0) e^{-j2k\sqrt{(x-x')^2 + (y-y')^2 + z_0^2}} dxdy$.

Comment: The decomposition as written seems to be invalid.  The right-hand side is clearly a solution to the Helmholtz equation whereas the term $e^{-j2kR}$ is not.  Perhaps there is a typo in the MTT article.

Answer (score 3):

$\nabla^2 f +k^2f =-\delta(x-x') \delta (y-y') \delta(z)$ is the Helmholtz equation with a point source at $(x',y',0)$ with well-known solution

$$\frac{e^{-jkR}}{4\pi R}$$

where $R=\sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+z^2}$.

Now, apply the Fourier Transform to both sides of the Helmholtz equation to obtain

$$-(k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2-k^2)F=-e^{jk_xx'+jk_yy'}$$

whereupon solving for $F$ and taking the inverse Fourier Transform reveals that

$$f=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int \frac{e^{-jk_x(x-x')-jk_y(y-y')-jk_zz}}{k^2-k_x^2-k_y^2-k_z^2}dk_xdk_ydk_z$$

Comment: I have updated the question. It is different from 3D Helmholtz equation. The source is fixed at $z_0$ along z-axis. Besides, FT is for $x'$ and $y'$, not $x,y,z$.

Comment: @HyZhang Is the source a point source or a line source? What is the location of the source (e.g., $(x',y',0))$?  What do you mean when you wrote "FT is for $x'$ and $y'$?

Comment: What is the physical interpretation of the function that you are representing?  There is no decay with distance from the source, which would be a violation of conservation laws.  And aside, what is $z_0$?

Comment: The source is a point located at $(x',y',z')$, as shown in the figure just added. The "FT is for $x'$ and $y'$ means $\iint_{R^2} e^{jk_{x}'(x'-x) + jk_{y}'(y'-y)+jk_z z_0}dk_{x}' dk_y' = FT^{-1}(k_x',k_y') e^{jk_x'x + jk_y' y + jk_z z_0}$

Comment: The author did not take into consideration the decay as it has no influence for the ad-hoc problem. The author wanted to use the signals acquired for millimeter wave imaging so only relative amplitude is enough.

Comment: Placing a prime on the subscript of $k_x$ does not really matter; it is a dummy variable under the integral after which obtains a function of $(x,y,z)$ and $(x',y',z')$.  In the post, there is no $z'$.  What happened to it?  Is there a link to the MTT article?

Comment: here is the link. http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=942570

Comment: I only have access to the abstract.

Comment: I have added a brief introduction to the physical picture in the end.

Comment: Yes.  I understand better.  Let me work on this.